# Use NineOldAndroids for flip animation on support fragments

Tags: android, animation, android-fragments, android-support-library, nineoldandroids

I am using support fragments in my app.
While replacing the fragments, I want a flip animation.
For that, I came across NineOldAndroid library but somehow, even after searching web, I am not able to use the animations on fragment transactions.

Please help.